# Advance internal array pointer to next record to fill jquery function to use insertAfter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm a jquery newbie and I'm trying to create a jquery function with information supplied from php. I'm sorting DIV to display in order of value with insertAfter. (Maybe there is an easier/better approach?) My issue is that I cannot advance the pointer to advance to the next record to fill my foreach loop.

**My PHP:**

```
$my_array = array("PETER"=>"100","LOIS=>"75","BRIAN"=>"25");
arsort($my_array);
```

**My jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var peter = $("#peterDIV");
  var lois = $("#loisDIV");
  var brian = $("#brianDIV");

  <?php

   foreach($my_array as $x=>$x_value)
    {
     echo strtolower($x) . ".insertAfter(".strtolower($x).");";
    }
  ?>
});
```

**Result of foreach:**

```
peter.insertAfter(peter);
lois.insertAfter(lois);
brian.insertAfter(brian);
```

I've tried to advance with next() and array_shift() but I think my syntax is off.

**EDIT**

**Desired Result**

```
lois.insertAfter(peter);
brian.insertAfter(lois);
```

I'm wanting the jquery to display DIV in order based on values received from a query to a sql database.

Comment: Hi there, I want to help but I don't understand what your desired output is?

Comment: see edit for my desired output. I'm thinking this is not the best or most efficient approach, however, it works up to this point.

Comment: Ok, give me a minute Ill write how to do it your way and how I would do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix for your solution:**

```
$my_array = array("PETER"=>"100","LOIS"=>"75","BRIAN"=>"25");
arsort($my_array);

$previous_key = '';
foreach($my_array as $key=>$value)
{
    // Check if first iteration of loop - if it is set the key and skip rest of loop
    if ($previous_key === '')
    {
        $previous_key = $key;
        continue;
    }
    // Same as your solution but sets the second one to be the previous key
    echo strtolower($key) . ".insertAfter(".strtolower($previous_key).");\n";

    // Updates the previous key with the current key
    $previous_key = $key;
}
```

Comment: Cool if you need any help with JQuery or PHP let me  know